# PHP & MYSQL, update record that is an exact match

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have a database that has primary key values of

```
John
John Clark
John Hall
```

I wasnt to update only John Clark and not the other two..

I have tried a select of

```
$sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM mydbase.mytable WHERE `username` LIKE '%".$usertable."%'";
```

$usertable contains the name i want to find in dbase ie "John Clark"

Once found i want to update and my SQL for this is

```
$sql4 ="UPDATE mydbase.mytable SET `picturecount` = ". $pictnumber  ." WHERE `username` LIKE '%".$usertable."%'";
```

What happens is all 3 names is being updated, can someone advise how i can update on the one that i am after, in this case "John Clark"

Comment: You can't use `LIKE` .You need to find a way to get the exact name and use `WHERE username=".$usertable`.

Comment: Tried -- $sql4 ="UPDATE fifebird_ticksummary.summary SET `picturelist` = ". $pictnumber  ." WHERE username='".$usertable."'";  and still the same , 3 being updated not the one i am after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` condition gets 3 rows and updates them, it's better way to dont use like in your `where` clause, better way you must put something stable to it, like `id` or something else, like `%john%` get 3 rows, and update them.

```
$sql3 = "SELECT DISTINCT username,id FROM mydbase.mytable WHERE username LIKE '%".$usertable."%'";
```

and second query like :

```
$sql4 ="UPDATE mydbase.mytable SET picturecount = ". $pictnumber ." WHERE username id=$sql3["id"]";
```

hope this help.

Comment: With the second Query i get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: try this : $sql4 ="UPDATE mydbase.mytable SET picturecount = ". $pictnumber ." WHERE username id=$sql3[id]";

Comment: Mohsen , after ammending as you suggest to above , i get  PHP Notice: in file /tickleaderboard.php on line 165: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: ok, can you tell me your table structure?, or can you fetch your $sql3 result with your sql driver(mysql,mysqli) and print_r it?

Comment: you must fetch your result into array , like : $result=mysql_fetch_array($sql3) or $result=mysqli_fetch_array($sql3), then print_r ($result)

Comment: try this, or if you have teamviewer , send me id , i do this for you.

Comment: @AndyG , please give me your remote control ID , not meeting id

Comment: in remote control tab ( on blue ribbon top of software click on it ) , then find your id part , and tell it to me..

Comment: 707 677 537    w3rk75

Comment: Mohsen --- 396ztq  please connect again have another issue with it

Answer (score 0):

You just use the below code:

```
  $sql4 ="UPDATE mydbase.mytable SET picturecount = '". $pictnumber .'" WHERE username =".$usertable;
```